# Multiple IF AND/OR Statement Returning Met/Not Met Text

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have been working on a formula for a couple of weeks now, I've looked online and on numerous occasions thought I had found the answer, but alas I still don't have a working formula.

I understand the rule that we should not ask duplicate questions, but from looking through StackOverflow I haven't found anything that has solved my issue. I thought this post was it - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753961/multiple-if-and-statements-excel#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753961/multiple-if-and-statements-excel#_=_) - but once again I could not get it to work.

So to my problem - I have two columns of information in table format:

Column 1 - SLA Priorities of Tickets from a ticketing system.

Example: P1, P2, P3, P4 Etc.. (P1 ~ Very High, P2 ~ High Etc.)

Column 2 - The initial response time to a specific ticket.

Example: 01:00, 00:44, 12:00 (01:00 ~ One Hour, 00:44 ~ Fourty Four Mins, Etc.)

I then want to add a column which will have a final value of "Met" or "Not Met". This will let me know if the ticket response was within SLA (Service Level Agreement).

PSEUDO CODE:

```
IF SLACELL EQUALS P1 AND IRTCELL <=1HOUR PRINT "MET", IF NOT PRINT "NOT MET", OR IF SLACELL EQUALS P2 AND IRTCELL <=2HOURS PRINT "MET", IF NOT PRINT "NOT MET", OR IF SLACELL EQUALS P3 AND IRTCELL <=4HOURS PRINT "MET", IF NOT PRINT "NOT MET", OR IF SLACELL EQUALS P4 AND IRTCELL EQUALS <=12 PRINT "MET", IF NOT PRINT "NOT MET"
```

One of my many Attempts:

```
=IF([@[SLA Priority]]="P1",IF([@[Initial Response Time]]<=1,"Met", "Not Met")),IF(AND([@[SLA Priority]]="P2",IF([@[Initial Response Time]]<=2,"Met", "Not Met")),IF(AND([@[SLA Priority]]="P3",IF([@[Initial Response Time]]<=4,"Met", "Not Met")),IF(AND([@[SLA Priority]]="P2",IF([@[Initial Response Time]]<=2,"Met", "Not Met")))
```

Can someone help me with this? I'm really struggling!

Thanks in advance!
Max

Comment: The question you linked is exactly your problem, and the accepted answer is exactly the solution!  I can't do any better than that answer.  The only thing I can add is that Excel stores all time or date values as days - so `01:00` is "really" 1/24 = 0.0416....  To use times in formulas you need `TIMEVALUE`  e.g. `TIMEVALUE("01:00:00")` is one hour.

Comment: I think we're missing some data here. If a P1 ticket had a response time of 1:00 (1 hour), was SLA met or not? What's the time limit for a P1 ticket? What about the other tickets?

Comment: P1 SLA - 1 HOUR
P2 SLA - 2 HOURS
P3 SLA - 4 HOURS
P4 SLA - 12 HOURS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working off of Davis' answer, I was able to come up with a working example. Assuming the time values are stored as in the example, I was able to get the correct answer:

```
=IF(
  OR(
   IF(AND(A1="P1",HOUR(B1)<=1),TRUE,FALSE),
   IF(AND(A1="P2",HOUR(B1)<=2),TRUE,FALSE),
   IF(AND(A1="P3",HOUR(B1)<=4),TRUE,FALSE),
   IF(AND(A1="P4",HOUR(B1)<=12),TRUE,FALSE)
  )
,"MET","NOT MET")
```

Assumuing A1 is the Priority and B1 is the response time.

You'll need to remove the spacing, I put it in there to make it easier for you to read...

HTH,
Zack

Comment: Wow, excellent! Thank you so much!

I thought it didn't work there but I was missing the brackets around the B1 reference. 

Thank you so much!! How do I reward on this website?

Answer (score 0):

With a lookup table (say named range `LValues`) a much simpler formula may suit:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,LValues,2)<B2,"NOT MET","Met")
```

This uses TRUE for the fourth VLOOKUP parameter (by default) so provided the table is sorted exact values are not required for matches.