# How do I write an If & sum statement

Tags: excel, ms-access-2007

I am trying to write a function that will: Multiply A2 & A3 if certain criteria is met in A1. If criteria is not met in A1, then I don't want anything displayed.

Answer (score 0):

IF(A1= condition,A2*A3,"")

After the condition, the first comma is the "if true" statement....and the comma after is the "if false" statement

Comment: If you need to do something with multiple outcomes for different conditions - you can stack them. See this article who explains it well.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753961/multiple-if-and-statements-excel

Answer (score 0):

Your title and question are asking two different things.

But to answer your question, this link explains how If statements work in Excel.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx