# Excel IF statement less than , between and greater than

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to write a query that returns a specific value based on an IF.

I've tried using the below to help me but just get errors

[Stack OverFlow 15753961](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753961/multiple-if-and-statements-excel)

Basically what I'm trying to do is

```
=IF(F6 < 10000 THEN "SmallTrack" WHEN BETWEEN 10000 AND 25000 THEN "FastTrack" ELSE "MultiTrack")
```

But obviously in excel language. Cells would contain numbers from 1 to 50000.

Comment: May I be so bold as to suggest you have a look at the [documentation for the IF function](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-GB/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett - You may be so bold yes. read through it and it actually helped me to understand where i was going wrong. Don't usually find helpful help on the office site. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

`=if(f6<10000,"SmallTrack",if(f6<25000,"FastTrack","MultiTrack"))`

The format of IF in Excel is *IF(condition,thenThis,elseThat)* - what I did was combine two IFs into one.