# Excel multiple IF, AND, OR nested statements - with date and time criteria

Tags: excel, datetime, if-statement, nested

I need to write an 'if' statement to output either DAY, NIGHT, or WEEKEND based on the day of the week and times as below:

output **DAY**      if the date and time is **Monday to Friday 7am to 9pm**
output **NIGHT**    if the date and time is **Monday to Thursday 9pm to 7am**
output **WEEKEND**  if the date and time is **Friday 9pm to Monday 7am.**

My data comes like this below in half hourly increments :

24/04/2015 16:30
24/04/2015 18:00
24/04/2015 18:30
24/04/2015 20:30
24/04/2015 21:00
24/04/2015 21:30
24/04/2015 23:00
24/04/2015 23:30
25/04/2015 0:00
25/04/2015 0:30
25/04/2015 1:00
25/04/2015 10:00
25/04/2015 11:30
25/04/2015 22:00
25/04/2015 22:30
25/04/2015 23:00
25/04/2015 23:30
26/04/2015 0:00
26/04/2015 0:30
26/04/2015 18:30
26/04/2015 19:00
26/04/2015 19:30
26/04/2015 20:00
26/04/2015 20:30
26/04/2015 21:00
26/04/2015 21:30
26/04/2015 23:00
26/04/2015 23:30
27/04/2015 0:00
27/04/2015 0:30
27/04/2015 1:00
27/04/2015 6:30
27/04/2015 7:00
27/04/2015 7:30

(theres a total of 17,000 rows of half hourly data for an entire year, SO I have altered some of the days and times so that it's easier to work with and there should be some data that matches all 3 of the DAY, NGHT, WEEKEND criteria)

I have studied this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15754238/1602250, and it makes sense but I can't get it to work.

I've output the day of the week into a 2nd column and tried this:

=IF(AND(A2="Fri",A1=">9:00:01 p.m.",A1="<7:00:01 a.m."),"WEEKEND") - but this needs to say between Fri9pm and Mon7am.

I've also tried this one, doesn't work either.
            =IF(OR(A2="Mon",A2="Tue",A2="Wed",A2="Thu",A2="Fri"),IF(A1=">7:00:00 a.m.", A1="<9:00:00 p.m.", "DAY", IF(AND(OR(A2="Sat",A2="Sun", "WEEKEND")))

Please can someone help, I'm going half crazy...

Comment: Will take some time to dive into this. In the meantime I'd recommend using http://excelformulabeautifier.com/ to keep your thoughts straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your data in column A, and datatype is text.
So I'll get date/time.

1. Column B: Get date: =DATE(MID(A2,7,4),MID(A2,4,2),LEFT(A2,2))
2. Column C: Get time: =RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-11)
3. Column D: Do req: `=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(B2)>=2,WEEKDAY(B2)<=6,TIMEVALUE(C2)>=TIMEVALUE(TEXT("7:00","HH:mm")),TIMEVALUE(C2)<TIMEVALUE(TEXT("21:00","HH:mm"))),"DAY",IF(AND(WEEKDAY(B2)>=2,WEEKDAY(B2)<=5,OR(TIMEVALUE(C2)>TIMEVALUE(TEXT("7:00","HH:mm")),TIMEVALUE(C2)>=TIMEVALUE(TEXT("21:00","HH:mm")))),"NIGHT","WEEKEND"))`

please see attachment. Hope this help.

[image]

Comment: Thank you both, I am trying your suggestions now.  If you replace the top 2 datetime stamps in A2,A3 with these
23/04/2015 21:30
23/04/2015 21:30
Does what you have built produce NIGHT in the top 2 rows in column D ??

Comment: Hi TQH, when i put your first equation -
=DATE(MID(A2,7,4),MID(A2,4,2),LEFT(A2,2)), i get 11/06/8959 as the output . but your attachment shows that it s outputting 24/4/2015, what am I missing ?

Comment: i have just uploaded file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1rj3HWgNB8GdEpraVJvS3M4WUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you soooo much.  I see the two NIGHT values at bottom of file too.  fantastc .  But when I changed one of the values in A1 from, say, 2130 to 2230,, it does that weird date thing again, and sets A1 as 'custom', and when i change it back to 'general'  it changes to a decimal number.    
  
23/04/2015 21:30 23/04/2015 21:30 NIGHT 5  
23/04/2015 22:31 11/06/9382 44444 #VALUE! 3

Comment: May be your input type: dd/mm/yyyy. I think we should input mm/dd/yyyy for date, and in the grid we change format cell to dd/mm/yyyy. And remember, i split DATA (Column A) so it should be format "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH -  I need to paste new date/time stamps every month, and got it to work this way:
step 1. Copy the original Data
step 2. Paste to Notepad (Prefer Notepad++)
step 3. Change the Cell Properties to TEXT
step 4. Copy All from Notepad
step 5. Paste back to Excel.