# Using IF formula in spreadsheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a table, example below, where users select the Priority and Complexity from a list of options and a number is assigned in the Rank column based on the combination of items in columns 1 and 2. I tried to re-work the formula [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753961/multiple-if-and-statements-excel), but I'm clearly missing something.

```
| Priority | Complexity | Rank |
| Low      | Complex    | 3    |
| Medium   | Complex    | 2    |
| High     | Unknown    | 1    |
```

The formula below works for anything with a *low* or *high* priority, but shows N/A for *medium* and I can't figure out why...

`=IF(G46="High",IF(H46="Simple",1,IF(H46="Complex",2,IF(H46="Unknown",1))),IF(AND(G46="Medium",IF(H46="Simple",1,IF(H46="Complex",2,IF(H46="Unknown",2)))),IF(AND(G46="Low",IF(H46="Simple",2,IF(H46="Complex",3,IF(H46="Unknown",3)))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula makes me shudder a bit. I've never been a fan of huge nested `IF` formulas because they are difficult to read, fragile, and easy to mess up.

I highly recommend just making a small reference table instead, then using an `INDEX`/`MATCH` approach to lookup the appropriate value. See example below.

Note you can put the table where ever you want, you can even hide it if necessary.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense - I'd started on a rabbit hole of nested IFs and didn't consider there might be another, simpler alternative!

Comment: @pwq Thanks for accepting the answer. Usually if I find myself going down a road of a ton of nested `IF`'s, I see if I can think of an alternative with a `CHOOSE` function (I recommend you look up this function also), but `CHOOSE` is generally only good for one-dimensional data. If two dimensional data is needed, I usually just use this approach here with a lookup table. This makes things much easier to read, and also allows for ease of changing the values in the future if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague has now solved this for me, thought I'd share it here in case anyone else can benefit:

`=IF(F2="High",IF(G2="Simple",1,IF(G2="Complex",2,IF(G2="Unknown",1))),IF(F2="Medium",IF(G2="Simple",1,IF(G2="Complex",2,IF(G2="Unknown",2))),IF(F2="Low",IF(G2="Simple",2,IF(G2="Complex",3,IF(G2="Unknown",3))))))`

Answer (score 0):

Embedded ifs are a nightmare to debbug/audit. Most of the times you can write a simpler function using Index(Match()) or Sumprod--

Here:

1. Create your table
2. Use a sumproduct :

   =SUMPRODUCT(--(B4:B6=G3),--(C4:C6=H3),D4:D6)

[image]