# Excel Efficiency of IF() versus AND() functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I tried searching, so forgive me if my searching skills are weak. I'm trying to slim down an Excel model for speed and filesize, and make it more legible, so I thought I'd replace a bunch of nested IF() statements with some AND() statements. I confirmed that the logic is the same, but my file exploded in size and I'm quite surprised. Is AND() horribly inefficient and worse than nested IF()? I can't share the formulas, but are there general suggestions for optimizing nested IF() formulas?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is unanswerable based on the details that you have given (none at all) but I would be surprised if there is anything about `And()` formulas which causes file size to explode. If it is a real effect, you should be able to reproduce it with formulas that you *can* share. Otherwise, I vote that this question be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Put the least common matches at the beginning of the nest. A worksheet IF 'short-circuits' meaning nothing is calculated after a condition is missed so if you have 100:1 odds of a match and 2:1 odds of a second match, the second will only be calculated 1% of the time if the 100:1 is first but 50% of the time if the 2:1 is first. Additionally, if your nested IFs are creating calculation lag then you bad data, bad formulas or both.

Comment: Most likely not related to the formulas if you somehow formatted cells outside of the used area. Save as .xlsb for smaller file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested `IF`'s are more efficient than `AND` in the sense that the `IF` *usually* won't bother calculating the rest of the formula that doesn't apply, e.g.

```
= IF(TRUE,<this>,<that>)
```

Generally, `<that>` in the equation above will be completely ignored.

`AND` **always** checks all conditions, even if unnecessary. E.g, consider this:

```
= AND(FALSE,<whatever>,<whatever>,...)
```

The result of the above equation will always be `FALSE` because the first argument is `FALSE`. (The remaining arguments are irrelevant if the first argument is `FALSE`.) Still, `AND` will check all of them anyway. `OR` acts the same way in this case:

```
= OR(TRUE,<whatever>,<whatever>,...)
```

In this way, `IF`'s are better becuase they "stop" after a condition is met.

Depending on the details of your spreadsheet (of which I know none), this could drastically affect calculation times especially if volatile formulas are used, which are known to spread like the plague to other cells in your spreadsheet if you're not careful.

However, I don't really prefer either. Nested `IF`'s are sloppy, difficult to read, and difficult to maintain. I practically always prefer a lookup table. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643955/using-if-formula-in-spreadsheets/) (and accepted answer) for an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and suggestions; I will see if the IF() can be reordered to place the most likely outcome first.

Comment: @PCM Please accept one of these answers by placing a checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

**File size will not increase because formulas are designed inefficiently but inefficiency could be caused by unnecessarily lengthy formulas.** In both cases, it's not number *number* of formulas that matters (since they are stored in plain text), as much as the number of **dependencies on other cells** since Excel stores separate **chain of calculation** information about each dependency.

You can check it out (and see why your file is so big) **by changing the Excel file's extension to `.ZIP`, opening it up as a compressed file, and examining files within**, comparing a previous (smaller) version of your file to this one.

An `.XLSX` file is just a compressed set of text `.XML` files.  An `.XLSM` adds not much more than a `VBAProject.bin` (binary file).

As was already stated, **efficiency of your *formatting*** can have a huge effect on file size. This can be improved by:

- **Using conditional formatting** (since a *rule* can format an area of cells that would otherwise need to have separate information stored for each cell)
- **Using built-in (common) formatting styles** instead of custom formats, which need to be stored individually
- An **overview of the file structure** [here](http://professor-excel.com/xml-zip-excel-file-structure/).
- Microsoft's **Official XLSX File Structure document**:  *Download **[`PDF`](http://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-XLSX/[MS-XLSX].pdf) or [`DOCX`](http://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-XLSX/[MS-XLSX]-171212.docx)***
- Stack Overflow : **[How to properly assemble a valid xlsx file from its internal sub-components?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922181(v=office.12).aspx)**

---

### More related information:

- MSDN : **[Excel Recalculation and Construction of a calculation chain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687891(v=office.15).aspx)**
- MSDN : **[Improving calculation performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/excel-improving-calcuation-performance)**
- **[The "Ultimate Guide" to Reducing File Size in Excel](http://www.excelefficiency.com/reduce-excel-file-size/)**
- Microsoft.com : **[How to minimize the size of an XML Spreadsheet file in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/325091/how-to-minimize-the-size-of-an-xml-spreadsheet-file-in-excel)**