# If(And( arguments + Vlookup not returning expected value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Spreadsheet (here --> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lzc7-WRxEBQc5D_SR0F-d-9PhQjmVk37UOgBQTGw3_Q/edit?usp=sharing) that performs several tests (ifs + And + Vlookups) in different columns in order to return a message, telling the user whether data is listed or not in different databases (the column that is performing the tests is Q, in tab Code extension data + Minimum desc. fill).

The problem is that I can't make it to work properly. It looks like I need more arguments to display the messages that I want, which would be "This is listed in..." or "This is NOT listed in...".

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2), "", 
IF(U2="No", "This code does not exist",
IF(AND(C2="Brazil", G2="USA", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]", 
IF(AND(C2="Brazil", G2="France", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'Brazil SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in Brazil SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]",
IF(AND(C2="Brazil", G2="USA", N2="Finished Good"), "There is not a list for BR FERT materials",
IF(AND(C2="Brazil", G2="France", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'FERT_Brazil price list 2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Brazil proce list 2019 [FR]",
IF(AND(C2="Chile", G2="USA", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Chile", G2="France", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'Chile SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in Chile SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]",
IF(AND(C2="Colombia", G2="France", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'Colombia SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in Colombia SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]", 
IF(AND(C2="Colombia", G2="USA", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Mexico", G2="USA", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Mexico", G2="France", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'Mexico SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in Mexico SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]", 
IF(AND(C2="Panama", G2="USA", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Panama", G2="France", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'Panama SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))),  "This is listed in Panama SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]", 
IF(AND(C2="Puerto Rico", G2="USA", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]", 
IF(AND(C2="Chile", G2="USA", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'FERT_Chile price list 2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Chile price list 2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Chile", G2="France", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'FERT_Chile price list 2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Colombia price list 2019 [FR]", 
IF(AND(C2="Colombia", G2="USA", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'FERT_Colombia price list 2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Colombia price list 2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Colombia", G2="France", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'FERT_Colombia price list 2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Colombia price list 2019 [FR]",
IF(AND(C2="Mexico", G2="USA", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'FERT_Mexico price list 2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Mexico price list 2019 [EUA]", 
IF(AND(C2="Mexico", G2="France", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'FERT_Mexico price list 2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Mexico price list 2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Panama", G2="USA", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'FERT_Panama Price Book [USA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Panama Price Book [USA]",
IF(AND(C2="Panama", G2="FR", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'FERT_Panama Price Book [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Panama Price Book [FR]",
IF(AND(C2="Puerto Rico", G2="USA", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'FERT_2019 Puerto Rico ICP List'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Puerto Rico ICP List [EUA]",

IF(AND(C2="Brazil", G2="I don't know", N2="Spare Part", W2="USA", X2="Z999607", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Brazil", G2="I don't know", N2="Spare Part", W2="France", X2="VFR02", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'Brazil SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in Brazil SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]",
IF(AND(C2="Chile", G2="I don't know", N2="Spare Part", W2="USA", X2="Z999607", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Chile", G2="I don't know", N2="Spare Part", W2="France", X2="VFR02", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'Chile SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in Chile SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]", 
IF(AND(C2="Chile", G2="I don't know", N2="Finished Good", W2="USA", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'FERT_Chile price list 2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Chile price list 2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Chile", G2="I don't know", N2="Finished Good", W2="France", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'FERT_Chile price list 2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Chile price list 2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Colombia", G2="I don't know",  N2="Spare Part", W2="USA", X2="Z999607", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Colombia", G2="I don't know", N2="Finished Good", W2="France", X2="VFR02", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'FERT_Colombia price list 2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Colombia price list 2019 [FR]",
IF(AND(C2="Colombia", G2="I don't know", N2="Spare Part", W2="France", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'FERT_Colombia price list 2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Colombia price list 2019 [EUA]", 
IF(AND(C2="Colombia", G2="I don't know", N2="Finished Good", W2="USA", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'FERT_Colombia price list 2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in Colombia SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]",
IF(AND(C2="Mexico", G2="I don't know", N2="Spare Part", W2="USA", X2="Z999607", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Mexico", G2="I don't know", N2="Spare Part", W2="France", X2="VFR02", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'Mexico SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in Mexico SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]", 
IF(AND(C2="Mexico", G2="I don't know", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'FERT_Mexico price list 2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Mexico price list 2019 [EUA]", 
IF(AND(C2="Mexico", G2="I don't know", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, 'FERT_Mexico price list 2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Mexico price list 2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Panama", G2="I don't know", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]",
IF(AND(C2="Panama", G2="I don't know", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'Panama SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))),  "This is listed in Panama SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [FR]", 
IF(AND(C2="Panama", G2="I don't know", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'FERT_Panama Price Book [USA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Panama Price Book [USA]",
IF(AND(C2="Panama", G2="I don't know", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'FERT_Panama Price Book [FR]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Panama Price Book [FR]",
IF(AND(C2="Puerto Rico", G2="I don't know", N2="Spare Part", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in LATAM SP_AffiliatesPartsPriceList2019 [EUA]", 
IF(AND(C2="Puerto Rico", G2="I don't know", N2="Finished Good", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'FERT_2019 Puerto Rico ICP List'!A:D, 3, 0))), "This is listed in FERT_Puerto Rico ICP List [EUA]",
IF(G2="I don't know", "Not possible to determine it") 
))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Yikes... I suggest you use a lookup table instead of dozens of nested `IF` statements. [Here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643955/using-if-formula-in-spreadsheets/48644819#48644819).

Comment: In your example formula you mentioned values from column G and N which is not shown in your sample spreadsheet. This nested IF formula is a poor execution of the look up logic. You should first analyse all look up criteria, then use several helper columns to determine if each look up criteria is met or not, and then perform the cross-sheet/workbook look up afterwards. Your current formula may simply fail when there is a new country or a new region which will change the look up criteria but the formula has already reached its characters limit. Again, try using helper columns as the first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I ended up doing was simplify the possibilities, by instead of trying to display cell content as "This is listed in..." or "This is NOT listed in...", I set them up for "This is listed in..." and "This is not listed at all".

I could not change the formula, because I have reached the maximum number of aguments, so I had to change my idea/mindset.

It worked.