# Excel - nesting the IF and AND function

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, nested

I was wondering if anyone could help with the following. I have found one [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753961/multiple-if-and-statements-excel) relating to my query (I think!!) but I can't break it down to do what I want.

I have created a spreadsheet and used the `IF` & `AND` functions to do half of what I want.
Basically if the answer is "no" in one column and one of four options in another (111,112,118,119) I want it to bring in the value of `C2`. This is what I have come up with:

```
=IF(AND(E2= "No",F2=112),C2,0)
```

This part works fine but I also need it to bring in the value of `C2` if "Yes" (`E2`) is selected AND the value of `D2` is equal to `F2` - this is what I have come up with

```
=IF(AND(E2="No",F2=111),C2,0),IF(E2 ="Yes",D2=F2,C2)
```

It doesn't work.
I found the answer linked at the top of the post, but my Excel skills aren't up to pulling it apart to fit what I want.

Comment: Did you copy the above text from another question?

Comment: Please, link the original question and explain your problem.

Comment: Hi, yes sorry the question was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753961/multiple-if-and-statements-excel

Comment: The problem is explained above although there was an error showing that wouldn't allow me to submit the question so I had to reformat some of it as code. Sorry it looks a bit of a mess,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't get the formula to work is because there are two separate formula thrown together in a cell:

`=IF(AND(E2="No",F2=111),C2,0)` - alone this is a complete formula and will return either C2 or 0.

If you want to nest your if statements you need to look at chaining them off each other: `If([something],[do this],If([something else],[do this],If(...` you get the point.

In terms of what you are trying to achieve there is a more effective method though, by using another formula, `MATCH()` that returns the position of a match in the list (array or range) you provide. You can just check whether the result of that formula is a number, like so:

`=IF(AND(E2="No",ISNUMBER(MATCH(F2,{111,112,118,119}))),C2,0)`

---

**EDIT**

So instead of providing 0 when the result of the `AND()` is false, we kick off another if that is your "Yes" clause... This then gives the 0 if it fails... Flip them round if you want "Yes" to be calculated first.

`=IF(AND(E2="No",OR(F2=111,F2=112,F2=118,F2=119)),C2,IF(E2="Yes",D2=F2,0))`

So the final result based off your comment would have been:

`=IF(OR(AND(E2="Yes",D2=F2),AND(E2="No",OR(F2=111,F2=112,F2=118,F2=119))),C2,0)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Richard, I really appreciate it. I have no idea about the MATCH function though and I cant see where the "Yes" option comes into this? Have you got any idea how I can actually use the IF function to achieve what I want? I will need to include the AND function presumably?

Comment: Edited the answer, hope this makes sense to you now, I would suggest playing around with it until you understand what is going on so that it sticks... `IF()` is the most useful formula in excel

Comment: Hi Richard, I have tried your suggestion but it is saying there is too many arguments? I have even tried copying and pasting it. Could there be a typo? To be clear I need the cell to display C2 if the answer is "no" and the cell number is 111,112 etc and it also to display C2 if the answer in E2 is "Yes" and cell D2 is equal to F2. Sorry to be a pain. This would be a massive help to my job if I can crack it and I will definatley play around with it to understand it properly. thanks

Comment: Sorry @James I missed the `OR() ` around the F2 logicals... There's no way F2 can equal 111, 112, 118 and 119 at the same time (oops)

Comment: Richard...your sir are a gentleman and a scholar! that's brilliant - its not quite there exactly as I want it but I will be able to work it our from here. It was my fault in the design of what I wanted. I really appreciate it mate. I am new to this site so if theres any rating or feedback I can give you just let me know. Thanks again !

Comment: No problem, this site is all about sharing knowledge and experience with others as long as you can see that they have put some effort in, in future a little fake data and the output you would expect from that data would usually help the explanation. You won't have the rep required to up-vote me yet, but if the answer I provide leads to your resolution, you can mark the answer as accepted by marking the tick to the left. You're welcome and welcome to SO ☺

Comment: Done, I really don't mind putting the effort in. I really like excel and its really satisfying when you crack something on your own but it looks like I was barking up the wrong tree here. Thanks again !