# Excel nesting - IF / AND Query part two?

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, nested

Hi I Had a query earlier and thought I had cracked it with the help of Richard  but [it doesn't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855971/excel-nesting-the-if-and-and-function/49857670?noredirect=1#comment86732993_49857670)

[image: e]

I have attached an image and what I am trying to achieve to make my query clearer.

```
* If E is correct then cell F will be set to match D manually               
* If E is yes and F is set to 111 then G will populate with the contents of C               
* If E is no and F is set to anything but 111 then it will return 0                 


* If E is correct then cell F will be set to match D manually               
* If E is yes and F is set to 112 then H will populate with the contents of C               
* If E is no and F is set to anything but 112 then it will return 0                 


* If E is correct then cell F will be set to match D manually               
* If E is yes and F is set to 118 then I will populate with the contents of C               
* If E is no and F is set to anything but 118 then it will return 0                 


* If E is correct then cell F will be set to match D manually               
* If E is yes and F is set to 119 then J will populate with the contents of C               
* If E is no and F is set to anything but 119 then it will return 0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Let me see what you are trying to do so I can steer you in the right direction... Edit the formula you have tried in to your question and give me a nudge ☺

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear, but sounds like this is what you're after:

[image: Table]

F2 = `=IF(E2="Yes",IF(OR(D2=111,D2=112,D2=118,D2=119)=TRUE,D2,""),"")`

G2 = `=IF(AND(E2="Yes",F2=111)=TRUE,C2,"")`

H2 = `=IF(AND(E2="Yes",F2=112)=TRUE,C2,"")`

I2 = `=IF(AND(E2="Yes",F2=118)=TRUE,C2,"")`

J2 = `=IF(AND(E2="Yes",F2=119)=TRUE,C2,"")`

Then just fill down.  I've put `""` instead of `0`, because it's a lot easier to see what's going on without zero's everywhere.  You can change them back once you're happy with the outcome.

Incidentally, sometimes it's easier to parse the code out.  Excel works fine if you have code on different lines, like the following for D2:

```
=
  IF(
    E2="Yes",
    IF(
      OR(
        D2=111,D2=112,D2=118,D2=119
        )=TRUE,
      D2,
      ""
    ),
    ""
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Aubs but I can do this part i.e. the "Yes" option, its the "No" option that I somehow need to combine in the cell. This is the third line in each section ? No worries if you don't know how to do it either as I really appreciate your response regardless. Thanks again !

Comment: Change the `""` to `0` does that give you what you want?

Comment: @Aubs you don't need to equate `AND()` / `OR()` against `=TRUE` as they already produce TRUE / FALSE... You are just adding a further calculation which could affect performance that would be either `IF(FALSE=TRUE` or `IF(TRUE=TRUE`, either way, they will just return the same Boolean.

Comment: @Richard Tompsett agreed, but for beginners, I prefer to write it out fully so they can understand what's happening and can see what the code is trying to achieve. Rather than just looking at a function same with `ISNUMBER()` etc. Show what the expected outcome is, in this case, I'm looking for `TRUE`, but equally, it could be looking for the opposite, in which case, you need to specify `FALSE`.